# Error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm looking to insert the ID of the current user into a table called Orders in my SQLite database

results is a variable that represents the current user that is logged in and looks like this:

```
existingAccount = input("Do you already have an account? (y/n)")
if existingAccount == "y":
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password:")

    find_user = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?"
    c.execute(find_user, [username, password])
    results = c.fetchall()
```

later on this variable is checked to see if the user is an admin to allow them to perform certain functions using results[0][3], the third column being the permission level.

My original idea was to use results[0][0] to fetch the ID and to add it to the table:

```
shopping = True
while shopping:

    itemToAdd = input("Please enter the ID of the item to add to the basket: ")
    basket.append(itemToAdd)
    print(basket)
    continueShop = input("Continue shopping?(y/n): ")
    if continueShop == "n":
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO Orders (UserID) VALUES = (?)", (results[0][0]))
        conn.commit()
```

Printing results[0][0] gives me the ID as I want however I am not able to insert it into the table and am given this when debugging.

[image: debugger]

Comment: Remove `=` from `VALUES = (?)`

Comment: You'll probably also need to use `(results[0][0],)`

Comment: thanks that solves one problem, now I'm getting "parameters are of unsupported type". I've tried creating a new variable that takes results[0][0] and converts it to int but it still gives the same error

Comment: ah, i removed the int convert and added a comma as you suggested, thanks for the  help, its seems to be working now